# Phalcon Rest Micro sessions not set

Tags: php, api, rest, session, phalcon

Iḿ trying to make an rest application using Phalcon, i save some of the info
of the logged in user in an session but i don't get this to work, my code:

```
    $this->session->set(  Sessions::USERINFO, array (
            'login'    => true,
            'type'     => UserTypes::ADMIN,
            'username' => $this->user->getUsername(),
            'adminid'  => $this->user->getAdminID(),
            'fullname' => $this->user->getFullName(),
            'avatar'   => $this->user->getAvatar() )
    );

    return $this->session->get(  Sessions::USERINFO );
```

When he returns the session it works but when i try to get the session in an other request it returns empty

```
    return array("session" => $this->session->isStarted(),
                 "session Data" => $this->session->get(Sessions::USERINFO));
```

isStarted returns true
get returns null

```
Sessions::USERINFO
```

is an class with const values

```
const USERINFO = "userInfo";
```

Session var creation

```
  $di->setShared( 'session', function () {
    $session = new Session();
    $session->start();

    return $session;
  } );
```

Comment: Please include your code as text, not a screenshot. It’s better for screen readers, small screens and the mobile apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Had to enable this in my frondend application:

```
    RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({
        withCredentials: true
    });
```

The frontend was not sending the cookie with every request.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this to save my session:

```
    $obj = $this->request->getJsonRawBody();

    $user = Users::findFirstByUsername($obj->username);

    if($user) {
        if($this->security->checkHash($obj->password, $user->password)) {
            unset($user->password);

            $this->session->set('auth', $user->toArray());
            $response = $user->toArray();
        }
        else {
            $response = array('msg' => 'failed');
        }
    }
    else {
        $response = array('error' => 'User not found');
    }

    $this->setPayload($response);

    return $this->render();
```

And this to recieve information from my session

```
    if($this->session->get('auth')['username']) {
        $response = $this->session->get('auth');
    }
    else {
        $response = array('msg' => 'noInfo');
    }

    $this->setPayload($response);

    return $this->render();
```

This is how I start my session:

```
$di->set('session', function () {
    $session = new SessionAdapter();
    $session->start();

    return $session;
});
```

It works just fine, you might want to try this.

Comment: I do use postman, only with postman it works he remembers the sessions but in the real posts send from my frontend it doesn't.

Comment: @TriPSs, I updated my answer with a code example. I use in my application, you might find it usefull.

Comment: can you maybe update your example with how you create the session variable? updated my question also.